# SSH to Google Compute Engine Instance Failing

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a simple f1 micro instance (Ubuntu 16.10) on Google Compute Engine. I had created a VPC (Networking) and allowed http/https. I explicitly created a Firewall rule to allow SSH (tcp:22). But I am not able to login to the VM instance.

I keep getting this error:
[image]

Here is my Firewall Rule:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you get an external IP? and assign it?

Comment: @dartdog Yes, I added an external IP address as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally ssh into an instance by Choosing "Automatic" while creating a new VPC network instead of Custom and also chose allow ssh. This added default Firewall rules which were more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into this problem I reached out to Google support by email (who responded!!)  and they instructed me to run the following commands from terminal (where I have [gcloud installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads)):

If you haven't yet authenticated / or to set the correct project

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

This is the meat of it - setting the firewall rules.

```
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22 --priority=65534
```

Also - use chrome - the interface seems to occasionally throw a fit whenever you use any other browser.